# SASS: Expression with Combined &:not selectors

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to understand what this SASS code will generate:

```
&--active, &:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):hover, &:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):focus {
   background-color: white;
   color: grey;
}
```

I am wondering about this part:

```
&:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):hover
```

The first part of the expression is clear to me `&:not(&--disabled)`.
This will exclude the class `&--disabled` when applying the styles written below. 
But what does it mean the scss next to it - `:not(&--inactive):hover`? And these `&:not` selectors used combined?

Also, this scss has some strange behaviour - on localhost this doesn't not work - does not apply at all, and when it is deployed on a test server, it got applied and works fine (it gets compiled and minified by gulp plugins).
Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not compile it and then reason about the output ?

into http://www.sassmeister.com/ put the following 
(`.parent` is just a parent rule which is needed to use the `&` parent selector)

```
.parent {
  &--active, &:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):hover, &:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):focus {
     background-color: white;
     color: grey;
  }
}
```

and behold:

```
.parent--active,
.parent:not(.parent--disabled):not(.parent--inactive):hover,
.parent:not(.parent--disabled):not(.parent--inactive):focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: grey;
}
```

---

so having the output we return to the matter at hand

> &:not(&--disabled):not(&--inactive):hover

is

```
.parent:not(.parent--disabled):not(.parent--inactive):hover
```

ergo

any `.parent` which does not have `.parent--disabled` and `.parent--inactive` classes will have a white background and grey color on `:hover`

(`.parent` is just an example here - could be `div`,`#foo`, ...)

Comment: Thank you, very clear explanation! What do you think - why is this css not getting applied on localhost - I mean, this part is not getting complied and applied at all. Only this part. But when it's deployed on test server, it's fine? Very strange.

Comment: @Julsy without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example it's impossible for me to answer the followup question